# Is it possible to reply to a message or card in MS Teams using the notification bot?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have an Azure function method that is an http trigger, and every time it is triggered, it posts an adaptive card in the channel in MS Teams. There is an example code :

```
string adaptiveCardFilePath = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "Resources", "NotificationDefault.json");
string cardTemplate = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(adaptiveCardFilePath, req.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
TeamsBotInstallation[] installations = await _conversation.Notification.GetInstallationsAsync(req.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
foreach (var installation in installations)
{
    // Build and send adaptive card
    var cardContent = new AdaptiveCardTemplate(cardTemplate).Expand
    (
        new NotificationDefaultModel
        {
            Title = "This message is send via Teams Notification Bot",
            AppName = "Azure Function",
            Description = $"test",
            NotificationUrl = "https://www.example.com/",
        }
    );
    var result = await installation.SendAdaptiveCard(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cardContent), req.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
}
```

```
private readonly ConversationBot _conversation;
private readonly ILogger<NotifyHttpTrigger> _log;

public NotifyHttpTrigger(ConversationBot conversation, ILogger<NotifyHttpTrigger> log)
{
    _conversation = conversation;
    _log = log;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the HTTP requests are related (for example, for the same customer), and then I want to reply to an already created one.

These are the nugets that I am using:

```
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core
Microsoft.TeamsFx
AdaptiveCards.Templating
```

I am aware that there are alternative methods for responding to a card in Teams, such as utilizing Teams Graph API or Teams REST API. However, I am encountering authentication issues with these approaches, particularly due to MFA protection.

I would like to ask, it is possible to respond to a card in Microsoft Teams using a Notification Bot ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to respond to an Adaptive Card in Microsoft Teams using a Notification Bot. However, the response to an Adaptive Card is not directly supported by the Notification Bot. Instead, you would need to use the Adaptive Card action handler feature, which allows your app to respond to Adaptive Card actions triggered by users.

Comment: As far as I know, the Adaptive Card action handler will capture an action when the user clicks the button in the adaptive card. However, I am not sure if it is possible to trigger an action with an HTTP request.

Comment: The handler will be called when the user interacts with the action in your Adaptive Card.